# Superclass and subclass each with it's own interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is the following ok? (keep in mind that I didn't write the bodies of the classes and I also didn't write the interfaces ;-))

```
abstract class SuperClass implements SuperInterface

class SubClass extends SuperClass implements SubInterface
```

Or is this generally considered bad practice?

What made me wonder is, that the following didn't work:

```
List<SubInterface> myList;
...
for(SuperInterface si : myList) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This code can't be right, please check it again.

Comment: Do you have reasons to suspect that this is bad practice? Can you explain those reasons?

Comment: Why can't be right ? looks fine to me

Comment: there's absolutely no problem in having a child class implement a different interface than it's father. you could even make your SubInterface extend your SuperInterface if you wished. the use of interfaces is a very good practise if done properly!

Comment: Where is `SubInterface` define here? Does `SubInterface` extends `SuperInterface`? In theory I think he wanted to write that but forgot, as he says it's a `SubInterface` of `SuperInterface`, so it isn't needed to implement that interface as it's already done implicitly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's neither good nor bad. `SubClass` here implements both `SuperInterface` and `SubInterface` (as well as interface defined by `SuperClass`' public methods). If that's what you need - that's fine.

As for your second example

```
List<SubInterface> myList;
...
for(SuperInterface si : myList) {
    ...
}
```

You declared the list of `SubInterface` elements, but want to fetch `SuperInterface` elements from it. If `SubInterface` extends `SuperInterface` then this has some sense. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct. Why not ?

Your SuperClass implements a SuperInterface which also implemented by your SubClass (thanks to the the SubClass extends SuperClass).

In addition, your SubClass implements another interface (SubInterface).

There is nothing wrong in your code/architecture.

```
SuperClass -- implements --> SuperInterface
SubClass -- extends --> SuperClass -- implements --> SuperInterface*, SubInterface
```

- Implicit implements due to the extends of SuperClass

Answer (score 1):

this is fine depending on what you want to achieve (there might be a better design for what you are trying to do), keep in mind that SubClass is both SuperInterface and SubInterface